# Overriding a read/write property to make it readonly

Tags: c#

I'm writing a custom control in C# based on TextBox.  I want the Text property of my control to be read-only (since only certain values are allowed in the textbox and I don't want the calling program to be able to put invalid values in there.)

I don't see how to do this. If I use public override Text {} the compiler inserts default get and set accessors. If I comment out the set accessor, the code compiles and runs, which I assume means the base accessor is being used. If I put readonly in the definition of my property, the compiler throws an error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

The issue here is that by trying to make a read/write property read-only, you're violating the contract of your base class. Your base class explicitly states that this property can be both retrieved and modified. Derived classes cannot break the contracts of their base classes, otherwise polymorphism would fail. Remember that if B derives from A, anywhere an A object is accepted, B must perform.

If that should not be the case for the derived class, then I would first question the design -- should this truly be derived from the base class? Is this truly an "is-a" relationship?

Assuming that we passed that test and truly should be derived, one approach -- which I don't personally like, but will share anyway -- may be to simply have the setter throw an exception. I personally don't like this, it still violates the contract, and feels like an excessive amount of cognitive friction in using your derived class, but if you truly have that solid a reason to do so ... well ... OK, I guess. But be sure you know WHY you're hacking around this.

But go back to the first point: Is this truly a scenario where a derived class is the **right** answer, from a design standpoint? Without seeing your code, my gut reaction is a no.

### EDIT

Somehow in my initial read of this, I missed the fact that we're talking about a UI control here. I stand by what I wrote above this edit, in the general property overriding case. However, in the case of a UI control, where the polymorphism opportunities (I hope) will be somewhat limited, and where the need may well justify this design, then my recommendation would be to have the Text property setter throw an exception.

A better design, in my opinion, would be composition. Make a user control, add the TextBox to the user control design surface with Dock=Fill, and then expose a new Text property which is readonly. You can also now expose only those properties you really want to.

Comment: +1 for composition, that seems like the logical choice here (though it wouldn't have occurred to me :) )

Answer (score 3):

You have to hide the base property by declaring Text with the "new" keyword.

```
public new string Text { get; private set;}
```

You can't change access rights with an override, so you cannot use the override keyword, as you've seen.  This way will "hide" the base implementation of Text, which isn't always a good idea, but as long as you know the risks it will work for you.

Comment: This will create a NEW property, not override the existing.  You will add confusion by doing this since one would expect to be able to set the property in the base and have it flow to the derived object.

Comment: Agreed about the new property.  Disagree partially on the confusion.  The whole purpose of being able to do this is to be able to control the perceived complexity of your API - if this is a business decision to hide potentially complex or dangerous functionality from the end users, then it's a good decision.  Every usage of "new" needs to be carefully considered.

Comment: what happens when someone has a base object, sets the property, and then casts your object? - the property value will be lost.  Hidden methods & properties are still available simply by casting to the base class.  Also, what happens when you try to pass your new derived object to a method that accepts the base as a parameter?  Your property values will be lost there as well - which is not something that anyone would ever expect to happen.

Comment: I fully agree with you.  I'm just answering the direct question.  The proper use of the "new" keyword is something to be learned from experience.  Not every control you make is meant to be extended or even exposed to other programmers, however, and there are lots of valid reasons for it.  It's in the language for a reason ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
public new string Text { get; private set;}
```

Comment: And with the "new" keyword comes the hiding vs. overriding issue: http://bit.ly/Ctfmb

Comment: In the Web Control it is a virtual property.

Comment: Yuriy: Yes, it is a virtual property. However, part of the property signature is the visibility level of the getter/setter. Attempting to compile code like this results in a compiler error: "Cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'classname.Text.set'"

Comment: This will create a NEW property, not override the existing. You will add confusion by doing this since one would expect to be able to set the property in the base and have it flow to the derived object.

Comment: Since you can't stop the casting, what about making it a public set, but override it to throw an error in the set?

Answer (score 1):

I think John Rudy may have a point here.  Inheritance is not the answer to everything.  If what you need to do is restrict a textbox so that only valid values can be accepted then perhaps you want to use a validation control to make sure that only certain values are allowed.

This way you get the behaviour you want by making use of the components Microsoft have provided us with.  No inherited class necessary.

Edit: If you create a subclass every time you want to modify the behaviour of a UI control you will quickly have an unruly inheritance hierarchy on your hands. For this reason I would suggest you consider composition to modify UI controls.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from others comments on overall design issues (which John Ruby explains nicely), you could always just override the setter to do nothing or throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that shadowing the property is the right answer, because any reference through the base will still work.  Since the property is virtual, you can override it and implement a setter that ignores changes or throws an exception.  I know it seems less clean, but it has the advantage of actually working.

*edit*

Looks like Yuriy Faktorovich made the same suggestion before I could.